# What is the difference and relation between policy and scheme in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I don't really understand the difference between the Policy and the Scheme concepts in ASP.NET authorization/authentication.

In the official docs I find this explanation: authorization policy can use scheme names to specify which authentication scheme (or schemes) should be used to authenticate the user.

Further down it talks about Policy schemes. I think I understand the idea of policies and the idea of having an authentication scheme, but having Policy, Schemes and Policy Schemes and not knowing the relation between them makes this a little bit confusing. What exactly all these concepts mean?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between Policy and authentication scheme? There are many authentication schemes, such as JWT authentication, Cookie authentication and so on. And a Policy can contain multiple authentication schemes. You can take a look at this document: [Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: So basically a policy contains one ore more authentication schemes?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has the same question:

**Scheme** - this would normally represent *"a way to authenticate or authorize users"*. We can have multiple schemes in ASP.NET core as in *"multiple ways to authenticated or authorize a user"*.

An example would be to use a **cookie scheme** or use a **JWT bearer scheme** (or both). With the cookie scheme we could authenticate a user by looking at the request header for a specific cookie and use that to determine who is the user. If we would use a JWT bearer we would look at the request header for a JWT token and use that to determine who is the user. If we use MVC we could use a particular scheme for a controller or action and another scheme for another controller or action.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0

**Policy** - This represents one or more requirements to authenticate a user. Each of theses requirements will have one (or more) handler that will handle the authorization.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Now when we want to authorize an authenticated user for a specific action we can specify the scheme to use (to authenticate the user) or specify a policy (when we need more complex requirements for authorization)

A policy when is defined normally it will use the default authentication scheme (because while the policy has some requirements it still needs to know which is the way to authenticated the user - which the scheme describes) but we can also specify ourselves to use a particular scheme or more than one.

**Policy schemes** refer to the fact that we can have more than one authentication schemes but we can use each one for a particular purpose. So we can use cookie scheme for general stuff, but for example we could use another scheme specifically for SignIn if for some reason we want this.

Some other useful links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/policyschemes?view=aspnetcore-7.0